# MySQL version of MongoDB Replica. OR MySQL MongoDB Driver

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Not sure if this is the right stack exchange site for this question so if it is can you please advise which one would be best.

Is there any way to either:
A)Have MySQL run via a dedicated driver / converter / server that converts the data and stores it into my current MongoDB Replica set.
Or
B)Have MySQL setup and have that data replicate over multiple servers.

I'm asking this from where my MongoDB Setup is LOTS more stable than MySQL. This is mainly from where I do have the replica set of two main servers and a third (designed just to be able to vote and store a copy of the data).

Thanks -

Ryan

Comment: "Have MySQL setup and have that data replicate over multiple servers."  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster

Comment: You're aware that MySQL and MongoDB are two _completely_ different things, right?